# A collection of n linked elements in Java

Tags: java, performance, collections

I need to store the following line items on a receipt: `quantity, description, upc, and price`.

What is the best method in Java to store these? I need to print them to an output at some point by line, just like a receipt printer would. The number of elements in the collection should be arbitrary though because I will be adding and deleting elements.

```
5 item1 new item 324234  $4.99
1 item2 dish soap 34235346 $6.33
```

..and so on

Comment: Linked list?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think about creating some objects that would reflect the items you want to represent. For example, perhaps you might have a `Receipt` object that has a `List` of `ReceiptItem`s.

```
public class Receipt {
    private List<LineItem> receiptItems;

    // ... 

    public void add(LineItem lineItem) {
        // be mindful of handling duplicates if needed
        receiptItems.add(lineItem); 
    }

}
```

Each of your items would contain the values you wish to keep track of

```
public class LineItem {
    private int quantity;
    private String description;
    private String upc;
    private BigDecimal price; // depending on the accuracy you need, you might be able to get away with double

    // ...

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    // ... add more getters to your heart's content ...
}
```

---

UPDATE:

To access the private methods, you would create a few getters or action methods. I've added a few above as an example.

Comment: Don't use doubles for monetary info, you will regret it sooner or later, but rather sooner.

Comment: Additionally, if you know they need to be represented a certain way by text, you can override the toString() method of the class (such as ReceiptItem) that you create.  That way, instead of having to code for each ReceiptItem a series of print statements, one for each field, you can just use System.out.println(ReceiptItem).

Comment: I like this response. However, I cannot seem to invoke an .add method for List<LineItem> receiptItems; with LineItem being the name of the class that you have as ReceiptItem. How do I access those private members and why does eclipse tell me that an 'identifier is expected after this token 'add'. receiptItems.add();

Comment: It would be hard to tell you where exactly your problem is without seeing code but my first guess is you are calling `add` outside of a method or a code block (perhaps you are calling it in the body of a class declaration, which is incorrect).

Answer (score 3):

Write a simple class with getters and setters for each arttibute to represent a line item. Then use a List to represent the sequence of line items in the receipt. Finally, you probably need a receipt class that has a list of line items, and a bunch of other attributes: dates, total amount, tax, etcetera.

It probably won't make any difference which List implementation class you use.  LinkedList would be fine, and so would ArrayList.  The difference in performance will be undetectable.

---

(Don't be tempted to try and represent this using an open data structure like a hash table.  It makes your code more complicated and much harder to maintain.  And open data structures are less time and space efficient ... if you are worried about that ... which you probably shouldn't be at this stage in your project.)